# How does the rupture limit of a cable depend on its length and cross-sectional area?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, material-science, spring, estimation

So I was doing my physics homework and found myself stuck on this question:

> A new composite material for the carrying cable of a lift should be used. In a test series in the laboratory, for a $2.5$ m long piece of cable with a cross-sectional area of $0.3\,\rm mm^2$ it was found that it breaks at $1100\,\rm N$. The cable planned for the elevator ($m = 2 t$) should be $20\,\rm m$ long and $1.2\,\rm mm$ in diameter. Is this material suitable for meeting the desired specifications?

I wrote down everything I have given, namely:

- 1st case (lab test):

  - $l_1 = 2.5\,\rm m$
  - $A_1 = 3 \cdot 10^{-7}\,\rm m^2$
  - $F_1 = 1100\,\rm N$
- 2nd case (cable in use):

  - $l_2 = 20\,\rm m$
  - $d_{A_{2}} = 0.0012\,\mathrm{m} \quad \Rightarrow \quad A_2 \approx 4.5216 \cdot 10^{-6}\,\rm m$
  - $m = 2000\,\mathrm{kg} \quad \Rightarrow \quad F_2 = mg = 19620\,\rm N$

But when I try using the appropriate equations I keep getting stuck on  equations with two variables.

I know, that $F=\frac{EA}{l} \Delta{l}$, $E=\frac{Fl}{A\Delta{l}}$ and $E_\mathrm{pot}=\frac{1}{2}D\Delta{l}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{EA}{l}\Delta{l}$, but I don't know what $E$ or $\Delta{l}$ are.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Could use a push in the right direction, maybe an equation I might have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the cable doesn't matter - you need to worry about the cross section. Think of the thick cable as being made up of many strands of the thin cable, each carrying a fraction of the total weight.

How many strands would there be - what force would each of them carry?

Note - the dimension of one cable was given as cross sectional area; the other was given as diameter. You need to work a little bit harder to figure out the correct conversion... (you wrote $A_2 = 0.012~\rm{ m}$ but they gave the diameter, not the area - and 1.2 mm = 0.0012 m).

Incidentally - 1.2 mm seems awfully thin for an elevator cable. Regardless of the outcome of the calculation, I wouldn't want to be in an elevator car hanging off a thin piece of string like that.

Comment: Oh god, yes, I totally went past the units there, thanks

Comment: So by this logic the cable wouldn't be strong enough, since $A_2$ is roughly $15A_1$, but $F_2$ is about $17F_1$, am I getting it right?

Comment: I didn't check your math, but the reasoning looks about right. Note also that you would want a HUGE safety factor in your cable. Not just "it doesn't break under the static load of the elevator", but also "it doesn't break when the elevator is fully loaded, going down fast, and then the brakes come on."

Comment: I still can't really wrap my head around why are we allowed to leave the length out. It factors in the force equation after all. Do you mean that the length and $\Delta{l}$ won't be constant anyways since it's an elevator and thus can be neglected?

Comment: Whether the cable breaks depends on the cross section only - that determines the stress (force per area). How much it stretches depends on the cross section and the length.